# Can you burn multible subtitles inside a mp4 video, if so, how,

Tags: exoplayer

I want to know if it is possible to add multible subtitles inside a video, and maybe make a feature inside explorer and make it run the subtitles, if so, how?

And another question, let's say that I want to add a skip button inside exoplayer and I want it to skip from (for example) 00.00.05 to 00.00.30 but I want to hardcode that time inside the video itself so exoplayer will read it and show the button to skip, is that even possible??

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the usual approach is not to 'burn' the subtitles in to the video stream itself but to have separate subtitle tracks in the video container, e.g. the mp4 file.

This way the same video stream in the container can be displayed with different subtitle tracks and the player can allow the user choose the subtitle tracks to use.

For your second question, it would likely be best to ask as a separate question but the quick answer is likely that it is theoretically possible to add some functionality to ExoPlayer to allow it read a time from metadata or even analyse a number in the video itself, but I think it is unlikely this is available currently - I am not aware of it.